# redirect React traffic to Django REST in development

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

In production, my Django serves all API calls (`/api`) to Django REST services and rest (`/`) serves React static files.

So, when my React calls services, it simply calls APIs by calling `/api`.

However, it causes problem in development. `python manage.py runserver` 
serves Django REST in `localhost:8000`.
And React website is available at `localhost:3000` by `npm start`. It is a problem because `/api` calls `localhost:3000/api` instead of `localhost:8000/api`.

In order for Django to serve React code locally, we have to compile React code which is expensive to do every modification.

What is the best way to solve this issue? Should Django dev server somehow redirect the traffic from `8000` to `3000`? Or React dev server redirect?

Comment: Are you using Create React App? Then you can just add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`. `"proxy": "localhost:8000"`

Comment: @Tholle Thanks! I didn't know such field existed! Solved all of my problem!

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome!

Comment: wait what, you trying to run your react app and your django in same port? like all 8000? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what to proxy all `/api` requests to with the `proxy` field in `package.json` if you are using Create React App.

**package.json**

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}
```